# How to login as admin without social login on remark42 commenting system

Tags: remark42

I choose [remark42](https://github.com/umputun/remark) as my commenting system, I only offer anonymous access to leave messages, this is my docker compose config file

```
version: '2'

services:
    remark42:
        image: umputun/remark42:latest
        container_name: "remark42"
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
        environment:
            - AUTH_GITHUB_CID=12345667890           # oauth2 client ID
            - AUTH_GITHUB_CSEC=abcdefg12345678      # oauth2 client secret
            - AUTH_EMAIL_ENABLE=true
            - AUTH_ANON=true
            - REMARK_URL=http://10.10.10.22
            - SITE=remark
            - SECRET=abcd
            - ADMIN_PASSWD=1234
        volumes:
            - ./var:/srv/var
```

according to the [Technical details](https://github.com/umputun/remark#technical-details), it mentioned:

> Admin authentication (--admin-password set) allows to hit remark42 API
>   without social login and with admin privileges. Adds basic-auth for
>   username: admin, password: ${ADMIN_PASSWD}

I set my `ADMIN_PASSWD` to 1234, but can't find a way to login as admin, the only API to login required a social provider

`GET /auth/{provider}/login?from=http://url&site=site_id&session=1`

lots of [apis](http://GET%20/auth/%7Bprovider%7D/login?from=http://url&site=site_id&session=1) need admin authorization

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation (https://github.com/umputun/remark42#admin-users)  you just have to login using the way you want and put the userid in your docker-compose.yml file like this:

```
environment:
        - ADMIN_SHARED_ID=github_ef0f706a79cc24b17bbbb374cd234a691a034128,github_dae9983158e9e5e127ef2b87a411ef13c891e9e5
```